# Select every Nth row where N is dynamic

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-optimization

In a single query I'm trying to implement a decimation on a Database view (The view's size ranging on 10^7 elements). To do so, I'm trying to select every Nth element in a result set. Currently, the implementation I have is correct, but very slow (2-3 seconds) and I'm looking to find a faster alternative.

Right now I select my result set with row numbers, select that result set with each element's mod value, and finally select all elements from that result set where mod value equals 0 or the rownumber is equal to the total count (to retrieve the last element). To find the Mod value I need to get the total size of the inital result set and divide by 1000 (we decimate by 1000 as a fixed number).

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id, age, sex, height, weight, attendence_time, 
        EXP1.rownum, MOD(INITIAL.rownum-1, CEIL(COUNT(*) OVER () /1000)) AS person_mod 
        FROM   (
            SELECT id, age, sex, height, weight, attendence_time,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY attendence_time) AS rownum         
            FROM   person p         
              WHERE  p.age = :age            
        ) INITIAL 
    ) MODROW WHERE MODROW.person_mod = 0 OR rownum = (     
                                SELECT COUNT(*)        
                                FROM   person p     
                                WHERE  p.age = :age       
                              )
```

I've looked into NTILE, and although I can use it to separate my result set into a 1000 groups based on the rownumber, I'm not sure how to get just the first element from each group to have a decimated response.

Are there any recommendations on how I might be able to make it more efficient?

Since I have a Java backend, would it be better to return the initial large result set and decimate in Java?

Note I'm using Oracle SQL with JPA/JPQL.

Comment: Does this really need to be one query?  You wouldn't need to be dynamic at all if you queried once for the count and then again for the rows.

Comment: Would that provide a significant enough performance gain? I figured doing that wouldn't decrease the total time by much since you're still grabbing count initially.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` by itself should calculate quickly, especially if any index starts with `age`.  I have to think that `SELECT * FROM (select * from person where age = :age order by attendance_time) p WHERE MOD(rownum,:num1) = 0 OR rownum = :num2` will be faster, and Java can calculate `:num1` and `:num2` fairly easily.  If `age, attendance_time` is indexed, then both queries should be relatively fast, but your original query might perform fine then, too.